# GameCenter skinning

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center, gamekit

Is it possible to take data we get from GameCenter and create our own skin for it?

If so where can I access all the data we receive? The important data I want is current matches, everything else is not a big deal to me. Can anyone help?!

Comment: if this isn't possible, would it not be wise to grab the match data everytime you create a new match and then save it- it could end up out of sync if not done properly.. but if i could get it all synced then as long as I hit the proper GameCenter functions it should be okay and work? Good idea/Bad idea?

Comment: are you talking about turn based games?

Comment: Yea- I'm looking to hold the match data in my own UI to make it a more native experience instead of jumping back and forth between gamecenter and my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should get you going:

```
[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *matches, NSError *error))completionHandler];

[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *matchData, NSError *error))completionHandler];
```

Edit:

It would take a very long post to explain the whole process step by step, but here is the main idea:

```
[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *matches, NSError *error)){ 

for (GKTurnBasedMatch *myMatch in matches) {

// update your UI depending on the games. Below is just an example.. This part is up to you - update a tableView, manage a view etc..

int k = 0; // will hold the number of active players still in the game
for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in myMatch.participants) {

if(participant.matchOutcome != GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit){
k++;
}

}

if ([myMatch.currentParticipant.playerID isEqualToString [GKPlayer localPlayer].playerID]) {
//our turn

if (k<2) { //there are less than 2 active players - end game if it's your turn etc...

//end turn depending on your turn.
return;
}

//update your UI for that match..


} else { //not your turn

//update your UI - goes to their turn section for example

}

}


}];
```

Again I just wrote all of this from the top of my head so I'm sure there are mistakes but thats the main route you want to take. You want to get a list of your current matches - and list them according to whose turn it is or if the game is ended and other things.

Comment: Thank you for those- It spits back a lot of data. Is there a way you recommend to split the data into separate objects? This is my first attempt at this!